# For loop runs only once with an additional condition checking whether the number is even

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multiple-conditions

My code is:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; (i < 10) && (i % 2 === 0); i++) {
    arr.push(i);
}
```

so, why it returns arr = [0]; and not arr = [0,2,4,6,8] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it terminates the moment the condition evaluates to false.

it will run once add 0. then check the condition and terminate since 0%2 === 0.

this is a fix:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
    arr.push(i);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I completely overlooked that loop would break after condition is false... thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's because when `i` equals `1`, `(i<10) && (i%2 === 0)` returns false and the `for` loop stops.

Just set the `i%2 === 0` check in the `for` loop to make it work.

```js
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Or just `i += 2`

Comment: I prefer to set the logic outside of the `for` loop :)

Comment: why?...is double the iterations vs `i +=2`

Comment: This way it's much simpler to change it in the future :) 5 loops with a `push` ain't gonna kill your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop has two condition, when `i` is equal to 1, the loop breaks

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment `i` by 2

```js
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i = i + 2) {
  arr.push(i);
}
console.log(arr)
```